# Why does __class__ assignment work when classes have different __slots__?

Tags: python, class, variable-assignment, slots

From the [Python language documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots):

> `__class__` assignment works only if both classes have the same `__slots__`.

So this is expected:

```py
>>> class A: __slots__ = ('x',)
... 
>>> class B(A): __slots__ = ('y',)
... 
>>> class C: __slots__ = ('x', 'y')
... 
>>> B().__class__ = C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'C' object layout differs from 'B'
>>>
```

But this is unexpected:

```py
>>> class A: __slots__ = ('x',)
... 
>>> class B(A): __slots__ = ()
... 
>>> class C: __slots__ = ('x',)
... 
>>> B().__class__ = C
>>>
```

Why isn’t `TypeError` raised here?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots